# What is the phrase for something which you determine in advance as going to turn out bad?

Tags: phrases

Can you suggest a phrase for the following:
You determine in advance that something is going to turn out bad; setting yourself up for it; cynical.

Not a premonition, but begins with "pre" and I think it is of two words.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. How would you use the phrase in a sentence? Please edit your question to add a sample sentence that has a blank ( ___ ) in the place where the word or phrase would occur.

Comment: "Prepare for the worst."

Comment: *Prediction* and *predestiny* are both relevant, but neither carry any implication of *setting oneself up* for a bad experience.

Comment: precipice? A predilection for precipitous peril.

Comment: Well... you're either a *pessimist* or a *realist*. Depends on which side of the fence you're sitting... ;)

Comment: You could say it is 'damned to fail' if you don't mind 3 words without a 'pre-' !

Answer (score 1):

How about **presage**?

[**presage:**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/presage)

(noun) A feeling or intuition of what is going to occur. (The Free Dictionary)

(verb) To give an indication of something in advance. (The Free Dictionary)

(verb) Be a sign or warning of (an imminent event, typically an unwelcome one) [(Oxford Dictionary)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/presage)

or [**portend:**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/portend)

(verb) To give an indication of something in advance.

[**portent:**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/portent)

(noun) An indication of something important or calamitous about to occur.

Answer (score 1):

**foreboding**:

- (*noun*) fearful apprehension; a feeling that something bad will happen: with a sense of foreboding she read the note.
- (*adjective*) implying or seeming to imply that something bad is going to happen: when the doctor spoke, his voice was dark and foreboding.

(Source: Dictionary app on my Mac)

Example:

> As the election approached, his sense of foreboding as to the near-certain outcome led him to become increasingly despondent, then cynical.

Answer (score 0):

From [Merriam-Webster...](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self%E2%80%93fulfilling)

> **self–fulfilling** *- becoming real or true because it was predicted or expected*

...which is often used in the collocation *a self–fulfilling prophecy.*

Comment: The OP says it begins with **pre** and adds it is two words.

Comment: @Rathony: Perhaps OP's memory has let him down. Or perhaps he'll benefit from coming to realize that even though this *isn't* the specific term he was trying to recall, it suits his context better. Maybe *other* people in future might be looking for a term suitable for the context as described, and be glad they came across this page. Who knows? Who *cares?* It's not a guessing game.

Comment: @Rathony: The edit looks fine to me (particularly, because the *title* is now meaningful). Don't forget that some people might have strictly time-limited online access; you can't expect every OP to hang around watching and waiting for an answer on the same day they post a question. And even if this OP never comes back that shouldn't be a show-stopper. Questions where the answer is *only* relevant to the actual OP are pretty much inherently off topic anyway.

Comment: @Rathony: I don't think tags are particularly useful on ELL (or ELU), so I don't take much notice of them (I just looked, and it's not obvious to me a typical question tagged ***phrase*** is any different to one tagged ***phrase-request***). But to my mind, *setting yourself up for it* clearly implies *causing* an undesirable future to come to pass purely because of what you say/do/think, so I don't see the question as Unclear anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, [***presentiment***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/presentiment)

> presentiment: *noun* a feeling or impression that something is about to happen, especially something evil; foreboding.
>   [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/presentiment)